# Placing a call to onDestroy() inside onPause(): good idea to guarantee activity destruction?

Tags: android

I have an activity that gets launched in singleinstance mode. It only serves a purpose when invoked, and none whatsoever afterwards.

Now of course I have it rigged so theoretically speaking the user can't leave the activity without terminating it. That said, I know apps that allow to bypass this sort of behaviour, such as clutchpad.

Question: if I wanted to make really, really sure my activity died upon moving away from it (ie, if it fell in the backstack), is it save/recommended to call onDestroy within onPause, or is it a bad idea.

If a bad idea, then what is the correct way of achieving this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`onDestroy()` does not end your activity, it is called by the system when the activity is being destroyed. You override it so that you can clean up your activity (e.g. stop other threads you have launched from it) when the activity ends. You probably should avoid calling it, and just let the system call it for you when needed. If you wish to end your activity, call `finish()` instead.